# syntax differences between CJS & ES6 modules

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, commonjs

In CJS modules I would use `export` and `var plugin = require('plugin');`     to export/import
In ES6 modules I would use `export` and `import * as plugin from 'plugin';` to export/import.

Are there more syntax differences? are these ^ differences correct?

What does `export default` and `export *`?

Comment: In CJS, `export` (and `module.export`) is just a variable. In ES6, `export` is a keyword and has it's own grammar in the language!

Comment: @Bergi thank you, interesting. Go a intersting answer also that will take some minutes learn.

Answer (score 37, accepted):

CommonJS modules and ES6 modules are pretty similar, but they have some very important differences to be aware of. To answer your question directly first:

```
var plugin = require('plugin');
```

in ES6 would be equivalent to both

```
// Import all named exports of 'plugin'.
import * as plugin from 'plugin';
```

and/or

```
// Import default export of 'plugin'.
import plugin from 'plugin';

// an alias of
import {default as plugin} from 'plugin';
```

but it depends on how 'plugin' has been written and whether it was written with ES6 `export` or CommonJS `module.exports`.

## CommonJS modules

CommonJS imports only have a single exported object. That object may be a function, or an object, or anything. Generally CommonJS modules do

```
exports.foo = ...;
exports.bar = ...;
```

to export named properties. They may also export a 'default' object as

```
module.exports = function(){};
```

The core thing here is that if you want both a default export AND named exports, your only option is to actually put the properties directly onto the default export.

## ES6 modules

For ES6 modules, the concepts of named exports, and default exports are 100% separated. e.g.

```
export var foo = ...;
export var bar = ...;
export default function fn(){};
```

The main difference being that

```
fn.foo !== foo;
```

With this example then, there are two cases

## Plugin used ES6 `export`

```
import * as plugin from 'plugin';

plugin.foo === ...;
plugin.bar === ...;
typeof plugin === 'object';

import plugin from 'plugin';

plugin.foo === undefined;
plugin.bar === undefined;
typeof plugin === 'function';
```

## Plugin used CommonJS `module.exports`

```
import * as plugin from 'plugin';

plugin.foo === ...;
plugin.bar === ...;
typeof plugin === 'object';

import plugin from 'plugin';

plugin.foo === ...;
plugin.bar === ...;
typeof plugin === 'function';
```

## Live Binding import/export

The other primary difference in your example is that `plugin` is a live binding. That means that if it is updated inside the module later, it will update itself in your import, e.g.

```
// plugin.js

export var foo = 'foo';

export function update(){
    foo = 'bar';
}

// other.js

import {foo, update} from 'plugin';

foo === 'foo';

update();

foo === 'bar'
```

and that would not be the case if you did

```
var foo = require('plugin').foo;
var update = require('plugin').update;
```

Comment: This was a very nice answer! `+1`. Can I use commonjs & ES6 syntax in same project in Node.js or io.js (I supose so, but wonder if there are issues to it I am not aware)? Will commonsjs modules disapear with time (maybe a subjective question...)?

Comment: Found also a interesting gist/article about this: https://gist.github.com/domenic/4748675

Comment: You definitely can use ES5 modules in ES6. I can't say for Traceur, but there is a standard interoperability layer included by Babel when you use `import` syntax that checks whether you are importing an ES6 module or ES5.

Comment: This is a repo for demonstration of the above theory: https://github.com/upupming/cjs-vs-esm