# Why does using babel preset-env with `useBuiltIns: "usage"` cause an error in harmony-module?

Tags: webpack, babeljs, babel-preset-env

I am attempting to configure babel preset-env to take care of injecting polyfills automatically, with respect to the specified list of target browsers.

The documentation states that configuring the `preset-env` preset with a property in the form of `"useBuiltIns": "usage"` will do exactly this.

(I noticed that specifying this property alone caused a warning to show in the console, however, stating that I ought to specify a core-js version to use, so I have added this too.)

Therefore, my `babel.config.js` is looking like this:

```
module.exports = {
  "presets": [
    "@babel/preset-react",
    "@babel/preset-typescript",
    [
      "@babel/preset-env",
      {
        "useBuiltIns": "usage",
        "corejs": 3
      }
    ]
  ],
  "plugins": ['macros'],
};
```

Fantastic! This should be a breeze!

However, having re-compiled with webpack, my app now dies in the browser, with a console message of:

```
Uncaught TypeError: __webpack_require__(...) is not a function
at Module../node_modules/webpack/buildin/harmony-module.js (harmony-module.js:24)
```

I've done some research (only about 3 hours worth!) and I understand this is the result of babel trying to transpile babel, or something of that sort...that I need to add some files to a list of ignores that will not be transpiled, or doubly-transpiled, perhaps.

In my webpack config, I've put the following. (Note the exclude entries).

```
module: {
  rules: [
    {
      test: /\.(js|jsx|ts|tsx)$/,
      exclude: [/core-js/, /regenerator-runtime/],
      use: [
        {
          loader: 'babel-loader',
          options: {
            presets: babelConfig.presets,
            cacheDirectory: babelCacheDir
          }
        },
        'eslint-loader'
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

I've also tried adding a few variations on the ignore pattern, but I still have fatal console errors.

Another thing I've tried, is ignoring the `node_modules` folder, but then I have big chunks of code that aren't transpilled at all. i.e. In IE11, I get syntax errors regarding ES6 arrow functions that originate in untranspilled vendor scripts.

If anyone is able to explain why `__webpack_require__` is being altered in an undesirable way, I would be very greteful, as the exact solution that this problem requires is being quite resistant to research.

Edit: The [following](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52407499/how-do-i-use-babels-usebuiltins-usage-option-on-the-vendors-bundle) suggests that *babel* must be made to ignore `core-js`, which seems very reasonable. It suggets using the following in the babel config file:

```
{
  ignore: [
    /\/core-js/,
  ],
  sourceType: "unambiguous",
  presets: [
    ['@babel/preset-env', { modules: false, useBuiltIns: 'usage' }],
  ],
}
```

However, this causes another fairly, seemingly nonspecific error to arise:

```
has.js:4 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot convert undefined or null to object
    at hasOwnProperty (<anonymous>)
    at push../node_modules/core-js/internals/has.js.module.exports (has.js:4)
```

Comment: Excellent question. It seems that setting `useBuiltIns: 'usage'` brings more Babel pipework into play than before, and things that used to just work (in my case, importing node.js-style code that exports using assignments to `module.exports`) now break. Using `sourceType: "unambiguous"` helped me, YMMV. (https://stackoverflow.com/a/52415747/435004)

Answer (score 2):

### Under `useBuiltins: "usage"`, Babel needs to take a guess wrt. ES6 vs. CJS import styles; and it better guess the same way as Webpack.

This is very briefly covered in [the Babel docs](https://babeljs.io/docs/en/options#sourcetype). The simplest way to make that happen, as explained [elsewhere](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52415747/435004), is to also set `sourceType: "unambiguous"` in the options passed to `@babel/preset-env`.

To answer the “why” question the best I can:

- `useBuiltIns: "usage"` means that Babel will set out to find and [polyfill](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polyfill_(programming)) a number of method calls (and other JS constructs) that may not exist in some browsers. This requires injecting some fixup code into your module at Babel rewrite time.
- A lot of these fixups consist of importing pieces of `core-js` to ensure that the Array etc. prototypes are populated to satisfaction; e.g. Babel may insert things such as

  ```
  import "core-js/modules/es.array.map.js";
  ```
- There is, quite unfortunately, [more than one way to import things](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31142842/435004) in JavaScript. Babel has to take a guess at which one is best for the downstream tool chain. If Babel is upstream of Webpack, which is a pretty typical scenario (and is the case for your question), it could derail some [auto-detection logic in Webpack](https://github.com/webpack/webpack/search?q=HarmonyDetectionParserPlugin) by adding `import` statements into code that uses `require()` or `module.exports`.
- Instead of throwing a parse error outright, Webpack will unfortunately try and process such tainted code; causing a variety of inscrutable compile-time or run-time symptoms down the line ([here is another example](https://stackoverflow.com/q/52407499/435004)).

Until such time that Babel and Webpack agree on some sort of convention or secret handshake that papers over the ES6 / CJS impedance mismatch, you as a module author will have to make sure somehow that Babel and Webpack have the same idea of which source file is using which format; or just disable Babel for your “old“ (CJS) code, whether in `node_modules/` or elsewhere.

Answer (score 0):

Excluding `/webpack/` did the trick for me !